# Breeze 0.73.3 does not properly publish hasChanges after a save

Tags: breeze

Using Breeze 0.73.3.  Modeling my app based on John Papa's Breeze version of Code Camper - http://www.johnpapa.net/recent-presentation-on-spa-basics/.  There seems to be a problem with manager.hasChanges.  Manager.rejectChanges() publishes hasChanges to false.  Manager.saveChanges() does not publish any changes to hasChanges.  Of course, it should be published to false following a successful save.

Comment: Bug confirmed. Working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch!  This is now fixed in v 0.73.6 available via nuget or the breeze website.

Comment: You might ask John P to re-publish

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Exceptional product!

Comment: I just updated my Code Camper Jump Start demo with the latest BreezeJS version. Thanks for fixing this Breeze folks. Link to the demo code is in this post: http://www.johnpapa.net/recent-presentation-on-spa-basics/.

Comment: @CCPony - Should be fixed now. If Jay's answer (and fix) satisfied you, please click the tick mark under the up/down to indicate that you accept it. Thx.